# Tempo de vida da conversa tida via chat devido a excesso de comentários

Tags: suporte, comentários, chat

Começam a surgir as conversas via chat principalmente oriundas da sugestão do *sistema* quando dois ou mais utilizadores trocam muitos comentários entre si:

[image: Captura de Tela]

Atendendo que grande parte do resultado nessas conversas é uma elaboração do problema onde os comentários estavam a ser usados para clarificar e/ou ajudar, o conteúdo do chat pode-se revelar proveitoso para alguém a passar pelo mesmo cenário no futuro.

## Surge-me então a duvida

Este tipo de chat tem tempo de vida limitado ou existe alguém responsável por o manter e/ou apagar?

Comment: No momento estou a deixar as janelas de chat abertas para as manter vivas, mas obviamente que... né... :)

Answer (score 1):

Eu acredito que a boa prática nesse contexto seria a criação, por parte dos interlocutores, de uma **pergunta formal** no site - até mesmo utilizando-se da função *Responder sua própria pergunta*.

O chat não me parece o local correto para repositório de conhecimento.

Comment: Nota que estou a falar do Chat que o sistema sugere e abre quando já existem muitos comentários por baixo de uma resposta. Ou seja, já existe pergunta e resposta de forma oficial, mas estar a passar tudo o que foi dito no chat para a resposta pode por vezes tornar a mesma extremamente confusa. Mas concordo que possa ser uma solução a actualização da resposta com um resumo daquilo que foi discutido e apurado no chat.

Comment: Entendo o contexto agora, @Zuul, e obrigado pelo esclarecimento; vou culpar a falta de café.